# Android - how to know when a particular layout is being closed

Tags: java, android, layout

So one of my android Fragments, the detail fragment in a master-detail setup, has several possible layouts, depending on what the user wants to do, and one of those layouts contains about a dozen EditText fields for the user to input data.

If the user inputs data, then switches to another layout or another Fragment (from the Detail to the master Fragment), I want to save what they have input so far before performing the switch, without requiring the user to do anything.  So I need to know when a particular layout ID was previously inflated and then gets deflated/destroyed/overwritten/etc.

How do I do this?  `onCreateView()`, where I am inflating the new layouts, seems insufficient because it doesn't seem to offer a way to access what was there previously, and AFAIK wouldn't be called if the user switches to the master Fragment anyway.  `getActivity().getCurrentFocus()` at the start of `onCreateView()` returns a View, but getID() doesn't seem to match when compared to `R.layout.my_layout`, and calling `getActivity().getCurrentFocus().findViewByID() != null` on an element in the layout doesn't work either.

Also, when do I perform the saving?

EDIT: Should I override `onDestroyView()` and run the save code there?  Whenever I try to do so, the app crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving and restoring your temporary data based on the Fragments layout IDs would be pretty much anti-pattern I guess.

Instead, add your input data as name-value pairs to the "instance state" `Bundle`, overwriting [`onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) of your Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myCheckboxState", myCheckBox.isChecked());
  savedInstanceState.putDouble("myDouble", 1.9);
  savedInstanceState.putInt("myInt", 1);
  savedInstanceState.putString("myTextViewString", myTextView.getText());
  // etc.
}
```

(adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151940/1140682))

This `Bundle` should is accessible in various lifecycle methods after your Fragment has been added to the container again. For example, by overwriting the `onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method, you may access this `Bundle` and pre-fill your form inputs using the respective setter methods.

Depending on your persistence requirements, you could also store your data more globally and not just in the Fragments instance state.